# Using only 3.3GB but I have 8GB RAM even on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ram

I have 2x 4GB(8GB) RAM installed on my motherboard and BIOS/UEFI can confirm it, but on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit only has 3424776kB or 3.266120911GB.

`uname -a` returns:

```
3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Through search, someone said about memory remapping but I can't find that on my Gigabyte F2A55M-DS2, I think that means it is on by default.

```
$ free -g
                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             3          1          1          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          1          1
Swap:            3          0          3`


$file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7d9cc5d4d6cb68aede9400492a7c5942c55c7598, stripped`
```

Comment: How are you checking how much memory is seen? What is the output of `free -g`? Also, as far as I know, the `uname` output you show only means your hardware is 64bit capable, not that you're actually running a 64bit kernel. In fact, it looks like you're not. What's the output of `file /sbin/init`?

Comment: Ensure that "Memory Remapping" is enabled in the BIOS ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier#Address_remapping ).

Comment: @terdon
free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             3          1          1          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          1          1
Swap:            3          0          3


file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7d9cc5d4d6cb68aede9400492a7c5942c55c7598, stripped

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich
As I mentioned, it can't be found on my motherboard's BIOS/UEFI settings. Some says that it is on by default on new motherboards.

Comment: Sorry @terdon, I'm not used to this site's formatting codes. Please check **EDIT 1** for your question. I'm not really a hardcore Linux user.

Comment: No problem, for future reference, the formatting tools are explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @eSPiYa oops sorry, you're right. I must've overlooked that :/

Comment: @terdon thanks! Anyway, what do you think is the problem?

When I try to run **dmidecode --type memory**

It says that the maximum memory is 8GB under Physical Memory Array.

Comment: I don't really know. I would try running a memtest and also booting into another OS to see if the RAM is available there. It is sounding more and more like faulty RAM and I don't know enought to judge whether it is possible that the BIOS thinks it's OK but the RAM is faulty. I would guess that yes but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is related to the updates and broken mirrors. Changed the mirror I'm using to a different one, updates were successful. After a reboot, performance became smooth and when I checked the RAM it already has 7.2GB(looks like AMD APU uses RAM too).

Answer (score 2):

**Check /proc/ tree memory file**

```
$> cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal: $MEMTOTAL
MemFree: $MEMFREE
Buffers: $BUFFERS
Cached: $CACHED
SwapCached: $SWAPCACHED
... ...
```

**Check DMESG Log for your Memory**

```
$> dmesg | grep "Memory"
```

**Invoke dmidecode to learn about your hardware**

```
$> dmidecode --type memory
```

Most likely, you are facing a hardware issue. Make sure your Motherboard's BIOS is completely up-to-date, and acquire a Return Materials Authorization for the memory from the supplier if the problem persists. Also try inserting the DIMMS into different ports.

**I remember something very important about PAE (Physical Address Extension) Enabled Kernels!!!**

Run this:

```
grep --color=always -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you see a $RETURN_VALUE here, you have PAE support.

The following command sequence will install a generic-PAE kernel on Ubuntu.

- Line 1 installs the package.
- Line 2 prints Kernel to screen.
- Line 3, 4, and 5 enables PAE flag in /proc/
- Line 6 checks to see if this has been successful.

> ```
> apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
>
> uname -a
>
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's\flags\t*:&pae' > /tmp/cpuinfo/pae
>
> mount -o bind /tmp/cpuinfo_pae /proc/cpuinfo
>
> mount -o remount,ro,bind /proc/cpuinfo
>
> grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
> ```

3.21GB memory access limitation is commonly a Kernel-driven issue. Your other option is to compile a main-line vanilla Kernel from Kernel.org and enable the CFLAGS for PAE extension.

32-Bit Kernel with PAE may work better than X64 Kernel. I have often had only a boatload of problems with X64 and hardware.

Comment: cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3424776 kB
MemFree:         1360372 kB
Buffers:           66616 kB
Cached:           628480 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB

Comment: dmesg | grep "Memory"
[    0.000000] Memory: 3222456K/3627964K available (7373K kernel code, 1144K rwdata, 3404K rodata, 1336K init, 1440K bss, 405508K reserved)

Comment: dmidecode --type memory
Maximum Capacity: 8 GB

Comment: I think PAE is already supported:
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm

Comment: Then switch to a 32-Bit PAE Kernel and see if that brings your RAM back.