# i have 3.3gb useable out of 8gb installed, x64 linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, ram, 64bit

after looking at the sys monitor i saw that out of 8gigs i only had 3.3 available. both of the 4 gig sticks are perfectly fine, and the slots are perfectly fine, but it shows 2x4gigs in bios, and 2x4 in lshw. i literally do not understand

OS: Linux mint 21.2 cinnamon. cinnamon ver: 5.8.4

lshw shows that i indeed have 2x4gigs of ram

```
  description: System Memory
  physical id: a
  slot: System board or motherboard
  size: 8GiB
*-bank:0
     description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
     product: 8KTF51264AZ-1G6E1
     vendor: Micron
     physical id: 0
     serial: 11A01A3A
     slot: A1_DIMM0
     size: 4GiB
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
*-bank:1
     description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
     product: 8KTF51264AZ-1G6E1
     vendor: Micron
     physical id: 1
     serial: 11A01A39
     slot: A1_DIMM1
     size: 4GiB
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

bios also shows 2x4gigs of ram

BUT

the system info shows i only have 3.3

and the sys gnome monitor shows that i only have 3.3

also, free -m output:

```
               total        used        free      shared   buff/cache   available
Mem:            3394        1122         887          24        1384        2016
Swap:          59558           0       59558
```

any information requested will be provided.

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158892/using-only-3-3gb-but-i-have-8gb-ram-even-on-ubuntu-14-04-64bit?rq=1

Comment: What does `file /sbin/init` return? Please add it to your question

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not sure, since here Mint 21 is supposedly only available as 64bit. It does feel like a 32bit issue though